# mstest does not copy a library referenced in a project but is used at run-time only

Tags: mstest

I have a project that uses Microsoft Enterprise Library and uses configuration to specify a type for caching manager.

Loaded in this manner caching manager depends on a library `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.dll` which **is** included in my test project as a reference, but the library **is not** being used by code directly (at compile time). As such the compiled mytests.dll will not have that library referenced (verified this using dotpeek).

**Question #1:** Why doesn't MSTest copy such library to the temp folder for testing?
**Question #2:** Is there an elegant workaround?

Not elegant solution **#1**: do a dummy reference to the included library (as mentioned [in this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/vststest/thread/3c5e0859-0638-4ca3-b2a4-e8a1b5700d4c));

or solution **#2**: use MSTest Deploy configuration to include the library explicitly.

solution **#3**:
Using a .testsettings file in mstest resolves the issue even if **deployment option is turned off**. I.e. testsettings file contains:

```
<Deployment enabled="false">
</Deployment>
```

Seems like doing this causes mstest to be ran not in the temp `TestResults\user_HOST 2011-12-21 15_22_08\Out` directory, but in the `bin\Debug` (where the library in question is *correctly* deployed to).

Is this an expected behavior of mstest? I mean the fact that mstest does not use temp directory if Deployment is disabled in the .testsettings file?

Comment: I use the same Enterprise Library suite of dlls for testing and currently use a testsettings file for deploying the proper config files and dlls. Most of the dll's I have chosen to set as Copy Local to false in the test project's references section and rely on the test settings to handle copying the correct files and dlls to the TestResults folder. To answer your question about the bin\debug as long as you aren't using the deployment option or have it specifically turned off it'll force the tests to run from the Bin\Debug rather than the \TestResults\User_Name_MachineName 2013-06-01 folder.

Comment: From MSDN Consider running your unit tests directly in the build output directory, so that testing runs more rapidly. This is especially useful on the build server after you have checked in your tests. 

To do this, add a .runsettings file to your solution, include <DeploymentEnabled>False</DeploymentEnabled>, and select the file in the Test, Test Settings menu. The same effect occurs in any test run in which DeploymentItemAttribute is not used at all. Source :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms182475.aspx